# Why is torch.nn.Sigmoid a class instead of a method?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to understand how pytorch works a little bit better. Usually, when defining a neural network class, in the **init**() constructor, people write self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid(), so that in the forward() method they can call the sigmoid function multiple times with having to reinstantiate nn.Sigmoid() every time.

But why isn't nn.Sigmoid just a method to begin with, instead of a class?

Also, I was curious what to refer to 'nn' in torch.nn as (package? library?).

Thanks!

Comment: torch.nn is a library with a bunch of modules like Sigmoid. Sigmoid is a "module" per the docs as it is a subclass of the Module class. Check out - "what is torch.nn really?" here https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nn_tutorial.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that the `nn.Sigmoid` exists to be composable with other nn layers, like this:

```
net = nn.Sequential(
      nn.Linear(3, 4),
      nn.Sigmoid())
```

If you don't need this, you can just use `torch.sigmoid` function.

Answer (score 6):

Sigmoid is available as both a module [`torch.nn.Sigmoid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#sigmoid) and a function [`torch.sigmoid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.sigmoid). The two are equivalent: the module is just a wrapper around the function.

The module exists mostly for historical reasons: PyTorch was based on the Lua torch7 package. In torch7, all differentiable neural network functions were implemented as modules. The module can also be used in [`torch.nn.Sequential`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#sequential) blocks for networks with simple feed-forward structures.

Other than that, there is no advantage to using the module form over the function form.

The `nn` in `torch.nn` stands for "neural network".